# In C#, how do you properly encode QBXML request with special characters

Tags: c#, qbxml

We are working on integrating QBXML with an application of ours and all is working pretty well until today when we attempted to create a new NonInventoryItemPart using the WebConnector.  Below is the XML we sent

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <ItemNonInventoryAddRq requestID="5468-22415">
            <ItemNonInventoryAdd>
                <Name>C-1531</Name>
                <IsActive>false</IsActive>
                <SalesAndPurchase>
                    <SalesDesc>Sumo Rucsac (225 lb +)… Single</SalesDesc>
                    <IncomeAccountRef>
                        <FullName>P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
                    </IncomeAccountRef>
                    <ExpenseAccountRef>
                        <FullName>C/S P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
                    </ExpenseAccountRef>
                </SalesAndPurchase>
            </ItemNonInventoryAdd>
        </ItemNonInventoryAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The response in the connection log was the well known error message of

```
0x80040400 :QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text
```

After some trial and error and internet searched, the `SalesDesc` inner text is what is causing the error, specifically (I think) the plus sign.  If we change the `SalesDesc` inner text to `Sumo Rucsac 225 lb Single`, this item is created successfully.

In C#, we need the ability to properly encode the request so that if other non acceptable characters appear, we can handle them appropriately.  However, I cannot find any good details on what characters (encoding) are accepted nor exactly what type of encoding to use so we are more bullet-proof in the future (eg UrlEncoding, HtmlEncoding...custom function?). I could maintain a list of characters to remove, but that seems like it would lead to a maintenance nightmare.

***EDIT*** - Thanks to @Amy below, the problem was narrowed down to `...`.  For a temporary fix, we are using `item.Name.Replace("...", "..");` to generate the inner text for our items.  I still think we will need a more robust character handling going forward, but since its not `+ or ( or )`, I feel a bit more comfortable with this band-aid for now.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `CDATA` element, maybe?  The `…` looks suspect.

Comment: @Amy - Thanks for the input!  I tried the CDATA tag, but I don't think QBXML likes that very much.  But...your pointing to the ellipsis yielded some good results.  It turns out it was not the parenthesis or plus sign, but `...` as only changing it to `..` worked as it should.  Interesting as this data comes from a text file, so its not an HTML ellipse entity or anything like that...?  I guess that specific combination of characters has a special meaning even if it is literally three periods in a row.

Comment: I have a hypothesis: the QBXML reader isn't treating the XML as UTF-8.  Maybe try specifying the encoding in the XML element?  (I don't know about the QBXML element).  I have no other constructive ideas.  Maybe the software reading the QBXML doesn't understand unicode strings?

Comment: @Amy - that's another good idea.  Admittedly, I am weak on encoding and XML so I'm learning on the fly!

Comment: How are you creating this XML? Using some XML aware component or plain string(builder)? A component would know about encoding special characters.

Comment: Info on the ellipsis character:  http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%A6

Comment: @HansKeﬆing - I am using the .NET XML document objects to create this XML - such as `var inputXmlDoc = CreateBaseQbXml();
            var qbXml = inputXmlDoc.CreateElement("QBXML");
            inputXmlDoc.AppendChild(qbXml);`  Specifically, the call for the item in question is `var desc = inputXmlDoc.CreateElement("SalesDesc");
                desc.InnerText = item.Name.Replace("...", "..");` - note the new replace addition :)

Answer (score 1):

The QuickBooks SDK doesn't handle [special characters very well](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbxml_questions#how_does_qbxml_handle_special_characters_accents_non-us_non-ascii_characters_etc) even if you specify utf8 encoding. You can sometimes escape characters to get it to import:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <ItemNonInventoryAddRq requestID="5468-22415">
            <ItemNonInventoryAdd>
                <Name>C-1531</Name>
                <IsActive>false</IsActive>
                <SalesAndPurchase>
                    <SalesDesc>Sumo Rucsac (225 lb +)&#8230; Single</SalesDesc>
                    <IncomeAccountRef>
                        <FullName>P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
                    </IncomeAccountRef>
                    <ExpenseAccountRef>
                        <FullName>C/S P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
                    </ExpenseAccountRef>
                </SalesAndPurchase>
            </ItemNonInventoryAdd>
        </ItemNonInventoryAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The response will not show the correctly encoded character, but it does show correctly in QuickBooks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRs>
      <ItemNonInventoryAddRs requestID="5468-22415" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
         <ItemNonInventoryRet>
            <ListID>80000005-1530119757</ListID>
            <TimeCreated>2018-06-27T13:15:57-05:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2018-06-27T13:15:57-05:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1530119757</EditSequence>
            <Name>C-1531</Name>
            <FullName>C-1531</FullName>
            <IsActive>false</IsActive>
            <Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
            <SalesAndPurchase>
               <SalesDesc>Sumo Rucsac (225 lb +)&#133; Single</SalesDesc>
               <SalesPrice>0.00</SalesPrice>
               <IncomeAccountRef>
                  <ListID>80000020-1530119204</ListID>
                  <FullName>P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
               </IncomeAccountRef>
               <PurchaseCost>0.00</PurchaseCost>
               <ExpenseAccountRef>
                  <ListID>80000021-1530119611</ListID>
                  <FullName>C/S P/A - Over the Counter</FullName>
               </ExpenseAccountRef>
            </SalesAndPurchase>
         </ItemNonInventoryRet>
      </ItemNonInventoryAddRs>
   </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```